# Is there a raylib function for c that can get one value from a Vector3

Tags: c, raylib

I am trying to get the y value of a Vector3 (the camera), and i have looked at the documentation and haven't found a function to get a single value from the Vector3.

I have tried using it like a list, but that obviously doesn't work. I have found some C++ documentation, but i am using plain C, and I don't want to mess with C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Vector3` is a [typedef of a struct](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raylib.h#L209):

```
// Vector3, 3 components
typedef struct Vector3 {
    float x;                // Vector x component
    float y;                // Vector y component
    float z;                // Vector z component
} Vector3;
```

So you can access the `y` field as with any other struct. If `my_vect3` is a `Vector3` then you can access it with `my_vect3.y`, and if `my_vect3_p` is a pointer to a `Vector3` you can access it with `my_vect3_p->y`.